# ReactJS: Call the method from remotely located JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Problem statement: I need to call 'a()' from remotely located file a.js

Code change in reactjs

`````
```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://localhost/test/a.js";
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.onload = () => scriptLoaded();
document.head.appendChild(script);````
`````

```
 scriptLoaded = () => {
 console.log("Script Loaded")
 console.log(window.document.all[2].src)
 window.a()
 }


File a.js

import b from './b.js';
export default function a () {
console.log("Print a")
}

File b.js

export default function b() {
console.log("Print b")
}


After removing the 'import' snippet and 'export default' from file a.js, I am able to call the method 'a()' from my react js code
```

````
function a () {
console.log("Print b")
}```
````

But I need to include and call the  method 'a()' from a.js with the 'import' statement, as the code have dependency on 'b.js' also